# file.path() vs. paste() to create URLs of varying length

Tags: r

I'm assembling a few path-to-file URLs.  Many moons ago, I would use `paste`, but nowadays we have `file.path` which is supposed to be faster.  The result I am shooting for is

```
[1] "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glfields.txt"   
[2] "http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/schedFields.txt"
[3] "http://www.retrosheet.org/boxfile.txt"
```

Notice that the third URL doesn't have a "middle" part `/.../` like the other two. So I try the following with `file.path` and get an incorrect third element, as expected.

```
dir <- "http://www.retrosheet.org"
mid <- c("gamelogs", "schedule", "")
end <- c("glfields.txt", "schedFields.txt", "boxfile.txt")
file.path(dir, mid, end)[3]
# [3] "http://www.retrosheet.org//boxfile.txt"
```

Changing the third element of `mid` to `NULL` just reycles `"gamelogs"`, which is strange.

```
mid[3] <- NULL
file.path(dir, mid, end)[3]
# [3] "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/boxfile.txt"
```

It seems I can get the result this way, but then why not just use `paste0(dir, mid, end)` without any arguments?

```
dir <- "http://www.retrosheet.org/"
mid <- c("gamelogs/", "schedule/", "")
file.path(dir, mid, end, fsep = "")
# [1] "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glfields.txt"   
# [2] "http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/schedFields.txt"
# [3] "http://www.retrosheet.org/boxfile.txt"
```

**Is there a trick to building these variable-length URLs efficiently using** `file.path`?

Comment: What about `sprintf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file.path()` is for local paths and not for URLs. Do not use it for URLs, or at least provide the separator explicitly, otherwise you might get a surprise in the future if the separator ever changes to `\\` on windows, for example.

`file.path()` claims to be faster, and may be indeed slightly faster on average:

```
system.time(file.path("foo", 1:1000000, fsep="/"))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.450   0.000   0.451 

system.time(paste0("foo", 1:1000000))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.602   0.008   0.611
```

So I would say, just use `paste0()`, it is fine.

The only problem with `paste()` and `paste0()` is that the code gets unreadable, but so does with `file.path()`.

Comment: Yep, going with trusty ol' `paste`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the way you are generating these are a bit odd. What if you had further separations of folders in the middle? It just seems that having three variables like that is a bit odd if you have variable length values. There may be a better way to store that information.

Anyway, one possibility is to use `cbind` to take care of the element recycling, then use `split` and `lapply` to perform the proper transformations. Here i write a helper function `blank.omit` to drop the zero length elements from the vector. As you can tell, `file.path` will not drop them automatically.

```
#helpers
blank.omit <- function(x) x[nchar(x)>0]
file.path.vector <- function(x) do.call(file.path, as.list(x))

#transformation
V<-cbind(dir, mid, end)
sapply(lapply(split(V, seq.int(nrow(V))), blank.omit), file.path.vector)
```

which returns

```
                                                   1 
   "http://www.retrosheet.org/gamelogs/glfields.txt" 
                                                   2 
"http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/schedFields.txt" 
                                                   3 
             "http://www.retrosheet.org/boxfile.txt"
```